# How can I switch back to the BigQuery features preview?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been using the preview mode of Bigquery for a couple of months and have gotten quite used to it (the tabs, the autocomplete, etc). I've also updated about 20 or so scripts to use the new comment character (# rather than --) so that I can use the shortcuts to comment/uncomment big blocks of queries.

This afternoon, I was suddenly reversed back to the old Bigquery and I cannot find a way to use the preview features again. I don't really want to change my scripts all over again... Is there something I'm missing? The "show preview features / hide preview features" option is not visible (it was to the right of the "Shortcut" button).

This page seems to indicate the preview mode should be the default: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui

Comment: I've tried rebooting my computer, and switching browsers from Firefox to Chrome, but this seems to be tied to my account rather than some locally saved configuration?

Comment: not just you, i see same - so looks like they rollback this (most likely temporarily)

Comment: looks like it is back now :o)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this seems to have been a temporary glitch in the matrix, it's back now.